# <option> append in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

I have a problem appending  tag in jQuery. 
The jQuery code is:

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
   .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select>');

$.each(companies, function(key, value){
    newTextBoxDiv.append('<option value = '+value+'>');
    newTextBoxDiv.append(value);
    newTextBoxDiv.append('</option>');
});

newTextBoxDiv.append('</select> </div></div>');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
```

But , it shows like all the options is not actually appended.The output i get is:
[image]

Comment: share the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proper way to create dynamic elements using jQuery

```js
var counter = 0;
var companies = [
  "companyA",
  "companyB",
  "companyC"
];

function selectBox(arr) {
  var select = "<select>";
  $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
    select += "<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>";
  });
  select += "</select>";
  return select;
}

function newTetBoxDiv() {
  return $("<div/>", {
    id: 'TextBoxDiv' + (counter++), // assign as ID and increment counter
    append: selectBox(companies),
    appendTo: "#TextBoxesGroup"
  });
}

// TEST:
$("#create").on("click", newTetBoxDiv);
```

```css
#TextBoxesGroup {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="TextBoxesGroup"></div>

<button id="create">CREATE TextBoxDiv</button>
```

Comment: @AlifNoushad you're welcome. Just please notice I changed/edited to ` $.each(arr, funct`

Answer (score 0):

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select>');
```

Should be:

```
newTextBoxDiv.html('<select>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`after()` function go to next element of selector and when you use html of after, next element html changing. So if you need to append select element to `#TextBoxesGroup`, you can build html string of the element and finally append to the `#TextBoxesGroup` element with [***appendTo***](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) function.

You can use this:

```
newTextBoxDiv = '';
newTextBoxDiv += '<select>';

$.each(companies, function(key, value){
    newTextBoxDiv += ('<option value = '+value+'>');
    newTextBoxDiv += value;
    newTextBoxDiv += '</option>';
});

newTextBoxDiv += '</select> </div></div>';
$(newTextBoxDiv).appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
```

Comment: actually my **newTextBoxDiv**  is as shown on my edit. How would i change it to a string? Thanks